# ¿Como atrapar el valor de un name que no esta directamente en el DOM con jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html5, vue.js

Tengo un formulario que crea múltiples `inputs` con un `append (jQuery)`, el problema es que cuando hago referencia a ese `name` para atrapar sus valores no me los toma, creo que es porque "no esta directamente en el DOM", como podria solucionar ese detalle, cabe mencionar que tambien uso `VUEjs`.

**CODIGO HTML**

```
 <label>Seleccione el tipo de pregunta</label>
                  <div class="form-group">                           
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <select  class="form-control" v-model="tquestion[index]" @change="createInputs(index)">
                           <option v-for="tpregunta of tipo_preguntas" :value="tpregunta.tipo_pre_id">{{ tpregunta.tipo_pre_name }}</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="input">

                  </div>
```

**SCRIPT CON VUE**

```
createInputs: function(index){

            $('.input').append(`
                <input type="text" name="test[${index}][]" placeholder="Ingrese Respuesta">
                `);
        },

set_pregunta: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log($('input[name=test]').val());
            return;
```

Ahora, si intento acceder de la siguiente manera `$('input[name=test[index]]').val())`
me muestra el siguiente error.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=test[index]]
    at Function.ga.error (jquery.js:4957)
    at ga.tokenize (jquery.js:5580)
    at ga.select (jquery.js:5867)
    at Function.ga [as find] (jquery.js:4502)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.js:6123)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery.js:6170)
    at n (jquery.js:3800)
    at un.set_pregunta (preguntas_controller.js:60)
    at t (vue.min.js:6)
    at HTMLFormElement.Ir.t._withTask.i._withTask (vue.min.js:6)
```

Comment: No sé si será de ayuda, ya que no entiendo mucho de Vue, pero, por lo que parece, estás intentando conseguir un `input[name=test]` sin embargo el valor se lo indicas como `input[name=test[index]]` por lo tanto no coincide y no lo encuentra

Comment: Hola @Rabegi, era una buena idea, pero lo intente y de una me tiro error, lo que me pone a pensar es que independiente de la cantidad de arreglos que tenga el input, con solo hacer referencia a ese name, deberia de mostrarmelos todos, ¿no? :/

Comment: ¿Qué error te daba? En principio, llamando a `input[name=test]` te cogerá solo los que correspondan a eso exacto, `test[index]` no lo mostrará ya que no coincide. Si pruebas a quitar el índice al crear los inputs y todos tienen `name=test` a secas ¿Te los encuentra?

Comment: Ok, Lo intentare. pero antes publicare el error..

Answer (score 1):

Estas creado inputs con el nombre name="text[1][]", name="text[2][]".
Para seleccionarlos con jQuery lo tendrias que hacer asi:

```
$('input[name="text[1][]"]')
```

Si quieres utilizar la variable index:

```
$('input[name="text[' + index + '][]"]')
```